# Save NSColor components to file

Tags: cocoa, swift2

I am trying to save an instance of NSColor to a file like this:

```
  writeF(node.lineColour.hueComponent)
  writeF(node.lineColour.saturationComponent)
  writeF(node.lineColour.brightnessComponent)
  writeF(node.lineColour.alphaComponent)
```

where the write function is:

```
  func writeF(var val: CGFloat) -> Bool {    
    let nsd = NSData(bytes: &val, length: sizeof(CGFloat))
    let rv = oStream!.write(UnsafePointer(nsd.bytes), maxLength: sizeof(CGFloat))
    return rv > 0
  }
```

And "node.lineColour" is just NSColor.blueColor().  It all compiles OK, but gives a run-time message at the first "writeF" line:

2015-10-01 07:57:43.871 canl[77917:8371660] An uncaught exception was raised
2015-10-01 07:57:43.871 canl[77917:8371660] *** -hueComponent not valid for the NSColor NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace 0 1; need to first convert colorspace.

Apple documentation on color spaces is very esoteric (if you already understand it then it's a fine reference, but if not then... good luck).  Why is the above code wrong?  Should be able to at least retrieve the color components (CGFloat).

Comment: Presumably you have something like:

   `var colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()`

You should probably change it to:


    `var colorSpace =  CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()`

Comment: NSColor conforms NSSecureCoding protocol. You should read this first [Encoding and Decoding Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i)

Answer (score 2):

After swimming through the available documentation and trying different things, I found this to work:

```
  let aColor = node.lineColor.colorUsingColorSpaceName(NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace)

  if let culoare = aColor {
    writeF(culoare.redComponent)
    writeF(culoare.greenComponent)
    writeF(culoare.blueComponent)
    writeF(culoare.alphaComponent)
  }
```

It also works for getting the hue, saturation, and brightness components, but I think I will go with RGB.